# Problem about BCH code

Tags: coding-theory, binary

I have another homework to do,  please give me some hints in order to solve this problem:

"Determine whether the dual of an arbitrary BCH code is a BCH code."

Comment: Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: Suggestions: look up the definition of BCH code: look up the definition of dual of a code: look at some other examples where there are proofs that one code is the dual of another.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The dual code contains all words $y$ such that $\langle x, y \rangle=0$ where $x \in C$. What can we get from that?

Comment: @Evinda, by itself, maybe not very much. But I also suggested looking up the definition of a BCH code. Maybe if you have that definition in front of you, it will be clear whether the dual of a BCH code is necessarily a BCH code.

Comment: According to my textbook: $$$$

The class of BCH codes is a generalization of the Hamming codes for multiple-error correction. $$$$
Let $\alpha$ be a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ and denote by $M^{(i)}(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^i$ with respect to $\mathbb{F}_q$. A (primitive) BCH code over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of length $n=q^m-1$ with designed distance $\delta$ is a q-ary cyclic code generated by $g(x):=lcm(M^{(a)}(x),M^{(a+1)}(x), \dots, M^{a+\delta-2}(x))$ for some integer $a$ . $$$$

Does this help?

Comment: @GerryMyerson So in order to show that the dual of a BCH code is not necessarily a BCH code we could show that the code is generated by less than $\delta-1$ minimal polynomials of $\alpha^i$, right? But how can we find such an example of a BCH code?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you could write down some simple BCH codes, construct the dual, and see whether the dual is also a BCH code. If not, you're done. If it is, maybe you begin to see why.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Suppose that we pick for example a binary BCH code with $n=9$ . The generator matrix of the dual code will be the parity matrix of the code, right? The parity matrix of a binary BCH code is of the following form:

Comment: $$ H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha & (\alpha)^2 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot &(\alpha)^{n-1} \\ 
1 & \alpha^2 & (\alpha^2)^2 & \cdot  & \cdot & \cdot & (\alpha^2)^{n-1}\\ 
1 & \alpha^3 & (\alpha^3)^2 & \cdot & \cdot &\cdot  &(\alpha^3)^{n-1} \\ 
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot &\cdot \\ 
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot &\cdot \\ 
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\ 
1 & \alpha^{n-1} & (\alpha^{\delta-1})^2 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot &  (\alpha^{\delta-1})^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$$$
where $\alpha$ is a primitive $9$-th root of unity .

Comment: Suppose that we pick $\delta=3$. Because of the form of the parity matrix, it has to hold that $n-k=\delta-1 \Rightarrow k=7$, right?

Then the generator matrix of the dual code is the following:

$$$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \cdots &  &  &  &  & \cdots & \alpha^8\\ 
1 & \alpha^2 & \cdots &  &  &  &  & \cdots & (\alpha^2 )^8
\end{bmatrix}$$

But since we are over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $a^k \in \{0,1 \}$ for any $k \in \{ 1, \dots, 8 \}$. But it has to hold that $a^i \neq a^j, i \neq j, 1 \leq i,j \leq 8$, since $\alpha$ is a $9$-root of unity...

Comment: But this isn't possible. Have I done something wrong?
 @GerryMyerson

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do we maybe have to pick an other $\delta$ ?

Answer (score 0):

hint: RS codes are the special type of BCH codes,their dual are BCH too and all RS codes are MDS code and the dual of a MDS code is MDS too